# Weekly RollingFileAppender in Log4j

Tags: java-8, log4j, log4j2

is it possible to generate log file weekly using RollingFileAppender  ? I am able to generate the file daily but would like to generate it weekly as the cron runs weekly twice.

I tried below code but it generates daily log.

```
log4j.appender.file.name=weeklycronlog
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=${app.root.dir}/logs/application_cron_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate log file weekly. Just replace the `log4j.appender.file.File` by the following value:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${app.root.dir}/logs/application_cron_%d{yyyy-ww}-%i.log
```

For example the file name would be: *application_cron_**2020_24**-xxx.log* means **24th week**, **2020 year**.

For more details you can visit [log4j-rolling-file-example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-rolling-daily-file-example/)